# Vue.js and vuex: this.$store is undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have already read the question with similar titles but I cannot follow them due to their complexity. I think with my code it will be easier to find a solution for me. I will only include the relevant code.

My store is this:
obs: I installed the vuex plugin.

```
   import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';


Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
    titulo: "please, change title"
}


const mutations = {
    changeTitle(state, title) {
        state.title= title
    }
}


export default new Vuex.Store({

    state : state,
    mutations : mutations
})
```

My App.vue

```
 <template>
    <div>
      <show-title-component ></show-title-component>
      <change-title-component></change-title-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>


import ShowTitleComponent from './components/ShowtitleComponent';
import ChangeTitleComponent from './components/ChangeTitleComponent';
import store from './vuex/store';

export default {

components: {ShowTitleComponent, ChangeTitleComponent},
store,
data: function() {
  return {title: 'placeholder'}
}


}
</script>
```

The component that generates the error:

```
<template><div>{{ title}}</div></template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "show-title-component",
    computed: {
      title() {
        return this.$store.state.title   /** error   here */
      }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: you need to include it in `main.js`

Comment: Include it in your entry file where you call `new Vue`.

Comment: I was redoing an exercise of a book to check if I have fixed the knowledge. I compared mine with the author's and couldn't  find any code mismatch. The only thing that I did wrong was to name the store file a .vue file. After I changed it to .js (store.js) it worked!

Comment: One more thing, after I renamed the store.vue file on my file system to store.js I had to restart the server otherwise I would get "store.vue" not found, or samething like that, on the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The store file should be Javascript (.js) file. Changing the file name and rebooting the server make the this.$tore error vanish.

The error was actually here :

App.vue

```
import store from './vuex/store';  /** in my case, it should be js file. */
```

Comment: @Diego Alves Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487276/how-can-i-send-data-from-parent-to-child-component-by-vuex-store-in-vue-componen

Answer (score 24):

Maybe, you have not included the `store` inside the **Vue** instance

Your App entry point (app.js or main.js or index.js) must include this code:

```
import store from './store'

new Vue({
 ...
 store,
 ...
})
```

then you can use `this.$store` in any component

but I recommend the general architecture: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/structure.html
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Your main.js File

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {store}  from './store'  //use curly braces to around store. 

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(Vuex);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using modules. I could access mutations, actions and getters without any issue. But not the state. Solution is when using modules state should access with the namespace of the module.

Check the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html) for more information.

```
const moduleA = {
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... }
}

const moduleB = {
 state: { ... },
 mutations: { ... },
 actions: { ... }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
    a: moduleA,
    b: moduleB
  }
})

store.state.a // -> `moduleA`'s state
store.state.b // -> `moduleB`'s state
```

> By default, actions, mutations and getters inside modules are still registered under the global namespace

Comment: Spent ages trying to figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.Make sure you create it a store directory

2.`npm i vuex -S`

3.Make sure `src／store/index.js` have `import Vuex from 'vuex'` and `Vue.use(Vuex)`

4.Make sure `src／main.js` have `import store from './store'`