# How can I send data from parent to child component by vuex store in vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

My parent component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <search-result/>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    import {mapActions} from 'vuex'
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        props: ['category'],
        mounted() {
            this.updateCategory(this.category)
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions(['updateCategory']),
        }
    }
</script>
```

My child component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.getCategory)
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getCategory'])
        },
    }
</script>
```

My modules vuex to send data between components like this :

```
import { set } from 'vue'
...
// initial state
const state = {
    category: null
}
// getters
const getters = {
    getCategory: state =>  state.category
}
// actions
const actions = {
    updateCategory ({commit}, payload) {
        commit(types.UPDATE_CATEGORY, payload)
    }
}
// mutations
const mutations = {
    [types.UPDATE_CATEGORY] (state, payload) { 
        state.category = payload
    }
}
export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

I try like that, but it does not works

If the code executed, the result of console.log(this.getCategory) in the child component is null

For example category prop in the  parent component = 7. Should the result of console.log(this.getCategory) in the child component = 7

Why it does not work? Why the result is null?

**Note** :

I can just send the category data via prop. But here I do not want to use prop. I want to send data via vuex store. So I want to set and get data only via vuex store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child's `mounted` hook is executed before parent's `mounted` hook. ( why? See [this link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/order-of-lifecycle-hooks-for-parent-and-child/6681/2?u=jacobgoh101))

`console.log(this.getCategory)` happens before `this.updateCategory(this.category)`.

Therefore, you get `null` in the console.

If you put `console.log(this.getCategory)` in `updated` hook, you would be getting the right value in the console later on.

Comment: I try change `mounted` to `created` in the parent component, it works

Answer (score 2):

**Jacob goh** has pointed out the problem.

To solve this issue you can make use of [`vm.$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) in the child component's `mounted` hook to ensure that the entire view has been rendered and the parent's `mounted` hook is called.

```
<template>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        mounted() {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                console.log(this.getCategory);
            })
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getCategory'])
        },
    }
</script>
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b82ouxmg/9/)

You can learn more about why use `vm.nextTick()` here: [Vue updates the DOM asynchronously](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)

Comment: I try change `mounted` to `created` in the parent component, it works