# When Unit Testing with headless chrome, Vuex Store is undefined

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, karma-runner, vuetify.js

I'm just trying to test a simple component. I inherited a project and it was set up with Vue CLI 2 and it looks very boilerplatey. My issue is I'm trying to unit test anything I devote to the project. However, I'm having issues with the vuex store coming up as undefined. It's preventing me from testing and I haven't figured it out yet.

I googled around and found multiple things including this. [Vue.js and vuex: this.$store is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814626/vue-js-and-vuex-this-store-is-undefined)

This is the error message I'm receiving

```
> cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run

07 08 2019 14:52:06.948:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/07 08 2019 14:52:06.958:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser ChromeHeadless with unlimited
concurrency
07 08 2019 14:52:07.006:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
07 08 2019 14:52:17.675:INFO [HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket KXXgp_cAT4JbkbufAAAA with id 2108708
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) WARN LOG: '[vue-router] Duplicate named routes
definition: { name: "load-balancing", path: "/networking/load-balancing/:ServiceRequestId/edit" }'
07 08 2019 14:52:20.798:WARN [web-server]: 404: /static/img/oops.png
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) WARN LOG: '[vue-router] Duplicate named routes
definition: { name: "resource-groups", path: "/portal/resource-groups/:ResourceGroupId" }'
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) WARN LOG: '[vue-router] Duplicate named routes
definition: { name: "manage-service-offerings", path: "/portal/admin/service-offerings/new" }'
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) WARN LOG: '[vue-router] Duplicate named routes
definition: { name: "manage-service-offerings", path: "/portal/admin/service-offerings/:Id" }'
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app'
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) WARN LOG: '[Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]

found in

---> <VDialog>
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>'
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) WARN LOG: '[Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]

found in

---> <VDialog>
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>'
ERROR LOG: '[Vuetify] Image load failed

src: /static/img/oops.png

found in

---> <VImg>
       <VCard>
         <ThemeProvider>
           <VDialog>
             <VApp>
               <App> at src/App.vue
                 <Root>'
ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in config.errorHandler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"'
ERROR LOG: TypeError{}
ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

found in

---> <UserDropdownMenu> at src/components/common/UserDropDownMenu.vue
       <Root>'
ERROR LOG: TypeError{}

  User.vue
    × should have a default value of false for user-menu
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
            at VueComponent.mappedState (webpack:///node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js:791:0 <- index.js:5858:31)
            at Watcher.get (webpack:///node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3142:0 <- index.js:10010:25)
            at Watcher.evaluate (webpack:///node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3249:0 <- index.js:10117:21)
            at VueComponent.computedGetter [as User] (webpack:///node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3507:0 <- index.js:10375:17)
            at VueComponent.userPhoto (webpack:///src/components/common/UserDropDownMenu.vue:35:0 <- index.js:25280:49)
            at Watcher.get (webpack:///node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3142:0 <- index.js:10010:25)
            at Watcher.evaluate (webpack:///node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3249:0 <- index.js:10117:21)
            at VueComponent.computedGetter [as userPhoto] (webpack:///node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3507:0 <- index.js:10375:17)
            at Object.get (webpack:///node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:1943:0 <- index.js:8811:20)
            at Proxy.render (webpack:///src/components/common/UserDropDownMenu.vue?bfff:19:26 <- index.js:85974:37)


HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.746 secs / 0.01 secs)
```

I just want to know why store isn't rendering correctly

Here is the simple test that I wrote

```
import {expect} from 'chai'
import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils'
import UserDropDownMenu from '@/components/common/UserDropDownMenu.vue'

describe('User.vue', () => {
  it('should have a default value of false for user-menu', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(UserDropDownMenu)
    const vm = wrapper.vm
    const data = vm.$data
    expect(data.UserDropDownMenu).to.equal(false)
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you provide code of your test?

Comment: Edited comment.